# Animating button border in swift

Tags: swift, animation

I recently learned how to animate a button using alpha so that it fades in/out in Swift. However, if I would like to only have the alpha of the border itself change, the animation does not seem to be working. Instead, it "jumps" from state to state.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: nil, animations: {            
  var borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.41, green: 1.28, blue: 1.85, alpha: 0.0)
  self.startButton.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
}, completion: nil);
```

The above code for example does not animate, instead it produces a "jump" between alpha 1.0 and 0.0 of the border.

However, this would work fine (changing the alpha of the entire button):

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: nil, animations: {
  self.startButton.alpha = 1;
}, completion: nil);
```

Is there any way to get around this issue?

Comment: Not everything can be animated with `UIView.animateWithDuration`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Features such as the `borderColor` and `borderWidth` are properties of the button's *layer*. That tells you that you must use core animation of the *layer* - not view animation, as your code tries to do - to animate such features. It works perfectly well; in this animation, I demonstrate what happens when you use core animation to animation the `borderWidth` and the `cornerRadius` together:

[image]

Animation of the `borderColor` would work similarly.

Comment: May I ask how I would go about animating the layer and not the view?

Comment: Read my answer above. You would use core animation. Core animation is direct layer animation. View animation works only for five particular view properties. Core animation works for _any_ animatable layer property.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a simple solution:

```
let borderWidth:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderWidth")
borderWidth.fromValue = 0
borderWidth.toValue = 0.9
borderWidth.duration = 0.5
yourView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
yourView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
yourView.layer.addAnimation(borderWidth, forKey: "Width")
yourView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 13):

You can't animate parts of the `layer` using `UIView` animations. Also, I don't think it's possible to animate the alpha value of the border. To achieve a similar effect you can animate the width of your border:

I made this `UIView` extension:

```
extension UIView {
  func animateBorderWidth(toValue: CGFloat, duration: Double = 0.3) {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderWidth")
    animation.fromValue = layer.borderWidth
    animation.toValue = toValue
    animation.duration = duration
    layer.add(animation, forKey: "Width")
    layer.borderWidth = toValue
  }
}
```

and then show the border of your view by using:

```
startButton.animateBorderWidth(toValue: 1, duration: 0.5)
```

and hide it by using:

```
startButton.animateBorderWidth(toValue: 0)
```